# Load pipelines from repository into ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a newly created ADF and I will have to configure the repository with the ADF. I have almost 100 count pipelines, their related datasets, linked services, triggers in the repository. How can I load all the pipelines and their respective into the ADF. Once I configure the git with the ADF I am unable to see the pipelines. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you select the below option when configuring the repo?  [image]

If yes double check the **Root folder** path. If it's not set accurately you will not be able to see pipelines, dataset etc.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps below to configure GitHub repo in ADF. Please make sure you also followed the same steps.

Enter name of GitHub repository owner. After this you will be redirected to login page of GitHub.

[image]

> Authoring directly with the Data Factory service is disabled in the
> Azure Data Factory UX when a Git repository is configured. Changes
> made via PowerShell or an SDK are published directly to the Data
> Factory service, and are not entered into Git.

Select your repository and fill required details.

[image]

You will get all Pipelines and Datasets as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

For more information follow [GitHub integration best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#best-practices-for-git-integration)

Answer (score 0):

In manage, got to Source control, GIT settings as below shown image,

[image]

provide necessary git hub repo details as done by you earlier and check the tick box on the "Import all the existing resources to repository" option and apply. You will get all your saved pipelines, datasets, and dataflows.

Hope this helps.